# Spark - how to skip or ignore empty gzip files when reading

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a couple of hundred folders with some thousands of gzipped text files each in s3 and I'm trying to read them into a dataframe with `spark.read.csv()`.

Among the files, there are some with zero length, resulting in the error:

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream

Code:

```
df = spark.read.csv('s3n://my-bucket/folder*/logfiles*.log.gz',sep='\t',schema=schema)
```

I've tried setting the `mode` to `DROPMALFORMED` and reading with `sc.textFile()` but no luck.

What's the best way to handle empty or broken gzip files?

Answer (score 25):

Starting from Spark 2.1 you can ignore corrupt files by enabling the **spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles** option. Add this to your spark-submit or pyspark command:

> --conf spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true

Comment: Where is this configuration documented? I didn't find it in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: It is not in official documentation but it's included in a Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19082
and cited by spark contributor Xiao Li in this presentation:
https://fr.slideshare.net/databricks/building-robust-etl-pipelines-with-apache-spark/20

Comment: It's not documented online for 2.3.0 either. To show all spark.sql.* config options - run this in pyspark: spark.sql("SET -v").show(n=200, truncate=False), where spark is a SparkSession object

Comment: I've tested spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles using pyspark and it doesn't handle empty gzipped csv files in S3. I haven't found a workaround other than writing a script to find and delete them.

Comment: @minus34, what was your strategy/approach for ignoring them? I currently have this hack-y approach of piping, within the program, stdout and searching for files > 0... Effectively like `hadoop fs -ls /input/folder/*.gz | grep <files where size is nonzero`... then iteratively loading each nonzero file and performing a union

Comment: @blacksite I used a Python script with Boto3 to go through the files in S3 and delete zero byte ones. Slow but effective

Comment: I'm running on Scala Spark-Shell. So far setting the conf as true `sc.conf.set("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", true)` has worked. The problem that I have though is that we're skipping the rest of the content. I assume there is still valuable information there and it looks like it only thinks empty rows are corrupted, because the partition values are empty rows. Example: `Skipped the rest of the content in the corrupted file: path: file:///..., range: 0-63489, partition values: [empty row]`. You can get this still running, but the exceptions are still being thrown